# Linq to XML, simpler way to select element with highest depth level in hierarchy

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to select the element with the highest depth (most nested) in hierarchy.

```
        var elems = my_list.Elements()
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name") != null && x.Attribute("Name").Value == "John")
            ;
```

Is there a simpler method than this one, together with filtering?

```
    XElement elem2 = null;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var elem in elems)
    {
        var depth = elem.AncestorsAndSelf().Count();
        if(depth >= i)
        {
            i = depth;
            elem2 = elem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "the highest depth" do you mean "the most nested"?

Comment: if you do `my_list.Elements()`, won't your max depth always be 2, if you never dig into the descendants?

Comment: Do not use 'value' because it will give error when attribute "Name" doesn't exist.  Instead use following : .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "John")

Comment: Thanks for hint. This is why I did  x.Attribute("Name") != null, I guess does the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) (either from .NET 6 or from the [MoreLinq package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq)) along with your ancestor counting:

```cs
// Note the change to use Descendants, as otherwise only direct
// children will be returned, which will all have the same "level"
var element = list.Descendants()
    .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == "John")
    .MaxBy(x => x.AncestorsAndSelf().Count());
```

Comment: MaxBy() is not available for .NET 4.8 that I'm using :(

Comment: @orfruit: Hence the "or from the MoreLinq package" part of my answer - you can use that in .NET 4.8.